# Question concerning blowups: Closed immersion $\operatorname{Proj}(A+\mathfrak m+\mathfrak m^2+...)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A[T_1,...,T_n])$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes, blowup

I am looking at the following exercise:

> If $A$ is a ring with maximal Ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, define $\tilde{A}:= A\oplus\mathfrak{m}\oplus\mathfrak{m}^{2}\oplus...$. Assume $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by elements $x_{1},...,x_{n}\in A$. Consider the map $\phi: A[T_{1},...,T_{n}]\longrightarrow\tilde{A}$, defined by $T_{i}\mapsto x_{i}\in\mathfrak{m}$. Show that this map induces a closed immersion $\operatorname{Proj}(\tilde{A})\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(A[T_{1},...,T_{n}])$.

Here comes my question: It is easy to see that $\phi$ is a surjection, so it induces a closed immersion of schemes $\operatorname{Proj}(\tilde{A})\longrightarrow\operatorname{Proj}(A[T_{1},...,T_{n}])$, but I do not see how there is a closed immersion $\operatorname{Proj}(\tilde{A})\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(A[T_{1},...,T_{n}])$.

So I think there should be a closed immersion $\operatorname{Proj}(A[T_{1},...,T_{n}])\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(A[T_{1},...,T_{n}])$.

I have little experience in algebraic geometry (but I know the basic definitions), and I do not even know where to start tackling this question. Please do not be too harsh on me.

Comment: Is the maximal ideal assumed to be nilpotent? If not, what should be the ring structure on this infinite direct sum (for instance, what is 1)?

Comment: No. The direct sum concerns only the underlying Abelian additive group. See Liu, Algebraic Geometry, §8.1.1

Comment: When you say exercise, where is this from?

Comment: from a worksheet my professor gave us. It is not on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong as stated (probably a typo on your professor's part). Your comment about a closed immersion $\operatorname{Proj} \widetilde{A}\to\operatorname{Proj} A[T_1,\cdots,T_n]$ is what's intended here.

The reason this is wrong is if $X\to Y$ is a closed immersion with $Y$ affine, then $X$ must be affine as well. But the only $A$-schemes which are both affine and projective are finite over $A$. So unless $\operatorname{Proj} \widetilde{A}$ is always finite over $A$ (it's not) you'll have no chance at a closed immersion into any affine scheme.

Comment: "If $X\longrightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion with $Y$ affine, then $X$ must be affine as well."

Can you give me a source for that? I want to be absolutely sure this is true before I hand in my take-home final in Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: I do not believe you are right: Liu, Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, §8.1.1, Definition 1.1 mentions a map from a projective scheme into an affine scheme. Or is that a typo as well?

Comment: @TheThinWhistler I would feel extremely uncomfortable assisting you on a "take-home final" you're currently taking. Until/unless you explain that you're not currently in the process of working on this final, I will have to avoid giving you any help and potentially remove my current answer (as well as perhaps flagging this post for attempts to cheat).

Comment: I am not working on it, promise.

Comment: I figured the entire exercise out already. It works perfectly fine with the map $\operatorname{Proj}(\tilde{A})\longrightarrow\operatorname{Proj}(A[T_{1},...,T_{n}])$. I was just wondering why it said $\operatorname{Spec}$ instead of $\operatorname{Proj}$.

Comment: @TheThinWhistler I stated that a closed immersion $X\to Y$ with $Y$ affine makes $X$ affine. Liu just talks about a map, with no assumption it's a closed immersion. For a reference about a closed immersion with affine target having affine source, see [Stacks 01QO](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QO). As for wondering why it said Spec instead of Proj, I answered this in my post: it's probably a typo.